# Convert code with that can throw to Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have following code

```
private void tryToLauch() {
        try {
            launch();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            postError(e.getErrorMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I convert it to Rx that will retry in some period in case of exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your method have as return type void, I suggest you to use a [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html).

You can try this solution, using RxJava 2

```
Completable myCompletable = Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            launch();
        }
    }).retry(3 /*number of times to retry*/, new Predicate<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            return throwable instanceof MyException;
        }
    });
```

Then subscribe to the Completable

```
myCompletable.subscribeOn(SubscribeScheduler)
             .observeOn(ObserveScheduler)
             .subscribe(this::onComplete, this::onError);
```

Hope this helps.